# Windows 8 reboots seemingly at random and reports PowerButtonTimestamp without the power button being pressed

Tags: windows-8, reboot

The issue is mostly explained in the title, however here's some more information:

This has happened several times, and I have never personally watched it happen. I've only seen it show up in the Event Viewer when I return to my PC being at the login screen.

This PC runs 24/7 for the most part, and the power supply is an 850w ABS from 2010.

Here are my temps and volts currently as reported by HWmonitor:

[image]

I am running Zune, iTunes, Chrome, Firefox, Visual Studio 2012 and Steam, so the CPU is under some load, 5-20%, but nothing significant.

Comment: check this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504

Comment: I would see if a fresh Windows 8 installation allows this to still happen.  If it does then its a hardware problem.